# flash: loading swf file within another swf in order to use it's functions

Tags: flash

i would like to load a flash file in order to use it's functions and classes. i would like that this file will be never cached. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866526/flash-actionscript/1866828#1866828). To avoid caching of the swf, you can append a random string to the SWF url like:

```
ldr.load(new URLRequest("Movie.SWF?rand=" + Math.random()));

//or

ldr.load(new URLRequest("Movie.SWF?rand=" + flash.utils.getTimer()));
```